# Custom header files and include libraries [C++]

Tags: c++, header, libraries

If I create a header like this:

```
#ifndef _MY_HEADER_H
#define _MY_HEADER_H

#include <iostream>
void foo();

#endif
```

With it's correspondent .cpp file, do I need to include ***iostream*** in the *main.cpp* file?

Comment: I think it's good style to include headers only in those places you really need them AND not rely on other include files to include headers for you. Hence: Yes, I'd include `iostream` in main.cpp, too. While you're at it: Check whether it's enough to include `iostream` in your `.cpp` file and not in the header.

Comment: @arne This is just an example, I was thinking of putting the "SDL.h", "SDL_image.h" and "SDL_mixer.h" in the header, and using them from there with my custom functions. Is it needed that I have them on my main file?

Comment: I would argue that in the case that @arne is describing, it is not necessary to include a header file in the accompanying .cpp again. Otherwise I agree that 1), you should only include header files in other headers if they depend on them for compilation, and a forward declaration doesn't help and 2) you should not depend on what other header files include (they might change their includes and leave your code broken).

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia I would argue that you don't need to include the SDL headers in the .cpp file that belongs to your .h file again, but there appear to be differing opinions on this. In any case you should avoid includes in header files if you can, otherwise your compilation times may skyrocket.

Comment: I agree with arne, however it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question: No you don't need to include it (again).

But it is good practice, to include in the header only the stuff that is required for the header to work. So if your `foo()` method requires `iostream`, you should include it. If you create a class that uses only pointers or references to other classes you should prefer forward declarations over inclusion of the full-fledged header of the respective classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to include it again in main.cpp, as in main.cpp version if you include the .h version of the same ,the inclusion will automatically be available in compilation, why write an extra redundant line?